# bootstrapValidator skip certain field

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrapvalidator

```
<input id="captcha_code" type="text" class="form-control captcha" name="captcha" maxlength="4" required>

password: {
    validators: {
        notEmpty: {
        },
        stringLength: {
            min: 6,
            max: 24,
        }
    }
},
captcha: {
    validators: false
}
```

I have a login form use bootstrapValidator, There is a field for captcha

I have set maxlength 4 & required for this field. I need validator skip and dont validate this field. (because when user enter wrong captcha code but it still show tick because length is correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting `required` on the `input`, you are telling the validator that it needs to validate the field.

If you don't want the validator to process this field, remove both `required` and `maxlength` and then handle the value checking yourself using an `onchange` or `onsubmit` handler, or another way.

Answer (score 0):

use this for disabling 
    captcha: {
           enabled:false
    }